# Flutter HTTP Request Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, flutter

Description:
I'm trying to make an HTTP request from my Flutter app to a Laravel backend, but I keep encountering an exception:

```
FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1).
```

I'm not sure what's causing this issue, and I've tried different solutions without success.

Here's my code:

```dart
static Future<dynamic> Submit(examID, answers) async {
  // answers demo data is
  // Map <int, int> answers = {1604: 1, 1644: 1, 1605: 1, 1647: 1, 1652: 1, 1625: 1, 1649: 1, 1610: 4, 1641: 3, 1606: 1};
    
  Map<String, int> answersStringKeys = {};
  answers.forEach((key, value) {
    answersStringKeys[key.toString()] = value;
  });
    
  dynamic answersData = jsonEncode(answersStringKeys);

  try { 
    // demo token is like 'lksdjflsdkfjlsadkfj djfasdkfjsadkfj;sladifjsdkfjalsd;kfjl;asf';
    final token = await FetchUserData.headers();
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://www.demo.com/api/Submit/$examID'),
      headers: token,
      body: answersData,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final ResultData = Result.fromJson(jsonData);
      print('get data');
      return ResultData;
    } else {
      print('not get data');
      return Text('get data');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    throw Exception('Failed to fetch result$e');
  }
}
```

On the Laravel side, I have the route set up to handle the incoming request, and I'm expecting JSON data.

```php
// Laravel controller
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function handleData(Request $request)
    {
        $jsonData = $request->getContent();
        $dataArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
        // Process $dataArray
    }
}
```

I've tried checking the JSON data in both Flutter and Laravel, and it seems to be correct. However, when the request reaches Laravel, the `json_decode()` function throws the `"Unexpected end of input"` exception.

Can anyone help me understand what could be causing this exception and how to resolve it? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!